# Summing an Array of Tuples

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, reduce

I have an an array of tuples defined like this:

```
var stringsWithLengthsArray:[(someString: String, someStringLength: Int)] = []
```

I've appended a number of tuples to this array. I would like to sum the someStringLength elements of each tuple in the array and think the best way to do this is to use the stringsWithLengthsArray.reduce method, but I can't figure out the syntax. What's the best way to sum the someStringLength elements?

Answer (score 4):

I like this way best:

```
let total = stringsWithLengthsArray.reduce(0){$0 + $1.someStringLength}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another solution. Use `reduce` without `map` and access your tuple fields with the .0 / .1 accessors directly.

```
let total = stringsWithLengthsArray.reduce(0){$0 + $1.1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to get only the someStringLength property value and use reduce to sum all the elements as follow:

```
let stringsWithLengthsArray:[(someString: String, someStringLength: Int)] = [("strA",2),("strB",3)]

let someStringLenghtTotal = stringsWithLengthsArray.map{$0.someStringLength}.reduce(0){$0+$1}

someStringLenghtTotal   // 5
```